# Extract ONLY valid bi-grams from a sentence

Tags: nlp

Looking for some ideas on how to tackle this problem that we have ..
we want to validate if a particular BI-Gram phrase is a valid phrase or not ..
say we have a sentence like "Xyz,inc is heavily investing into Digital Transformation" ...after stop word removal say we are left with "Xyz inc heavily investing Digital Transformation"

if we extract BI-Grams from this cleaned sentence we are having

- Xyz,inc heavily
- heavily Investing
- investing Digital
- Digital Transformation

In these combinations ONLY "Digital Transformation" makes sense ..

Any idea on how we can filter other bi-gram phrases extracted

Answer (score 0):

Be careful about that, when doing text-mining you can't tell in advance with certainty if a combination is valuable or not. When using n-grams it makes sense to let them into a model and prune with solid feature selection.